# blade <has> lower performance

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "has" in the following sentences correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> In fact, this above explanation shows disadvantages of constant
>   thickness blades. Meanwhile, it is possible that a variable thickness
>   blade **has** lower performance than to constant thickness blade because a
>   thin and variable thickness blade can be had low blade loading.

Answer (score 1):

The use of "has" is grammatical because it agrees with its singular subject blade.  However, the use of "to" after "than" is unnecessary.